# Creating Proper ARIA Menu with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, accessibility, wai-aria

I have created a custom Nav Walker for WordPress to add the proper ARIA roles to output of the `wp_nav_menu()` function. That checks out alright. But I am stuck attempting to do two things.

My walker produces the following output:

```
<nav id="siteNav" role="navigation">
<ul id="menuMain" class="menu" role="menubar">
    <li id="menu-item-1698" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/" role="menuitem">Front Page</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1697" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/blog/" role="menuitem">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1694" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/sample-page/" role="menuitem">Sample Page</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1695" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/page-b/" role="menuitem">Page B</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1696" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/page-a/" role="menuitem">Page A</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1699" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/" role="menuitem">Front Page</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1701" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="http://localhost/level-1/" role="menuitem">Level 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="false">
           <li id="menu-item-1702" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
               <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2b/" role="menuitem">Level 2b</a>
            </li>
           <li id="menu-item-1703" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
               <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2a/" role="menuitem">Level 2a</a>
            </li>
           <li id="menu-item-1704" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
               <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/" role="menuitem">Level 2</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="false">
                  <li id="menu-item-1705" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
                      <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/level-3b/" role="menuitem">Level 3b</a>
                   </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1706" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
                      <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/level-3a/" role="menuitem">Level 3a</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to do now is add some kind of ID to the `<a>` elements the are siblings to the `<ul class="sub-menu">` elements and reference that ID in an `aria-labelledby` property.

So the menuitem containing the submenus will look as follows:

```
<li id="menu-item-1704" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
   <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/" role="menuitem" id="{ID}">Level 2</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="{ID}">
       <li id="menu-item-1705" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
          <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/level-3b/" role="menuitem">Level 3b</a>
       </li>
       <li id="menu-item-1706" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
          <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/level-3a/" role="menuitem">Level 3a</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

The code for my walker:

class Walker_ARIA_Nav_Menu extends walker {

```
public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );


public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );


public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\" role=\"menu\" aria-expanded=\"false\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\n";
}


public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}


public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;


    $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .' role="presentation">';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';


    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }


    $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' role="menuitem">';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;


    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}


public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
}
} // End Walker_ARIA_Nav_Menu Class
```

Comment: Are you creating a web site navigation menu, or are you building an application that you want to function like a native OS application?

Answer (score 2):

I am going answer this under the assumption that you are building this menu for a web site or similar (not an application you install on your chosen OS that is supposed to behave as the native OS menus do).

That being said, I believe you have an overall ARIA issue here, which makes the PHP part of your question moot.

Right off the bat, given the following HTML you propose:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="{ID}">
    <li id="menu-item-1705" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
       <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/level-3b/" role="menuitem">Level 3b</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1706" class="menu-item" role="presentation">
       <a href="http://localhost/level-1/level-2/level-3a/" role="menuitem">Level 3a</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

…you should just skip the `aria-labelledby`. Since there is no tab stop on that element (I am not referring to `tabindex`), there is no reason for the screen reader to announce it, so it won't. In addition, if it *did* have a tab stop, the `aria-labelledby` overrides the accessible name that might otherwise be on that element. [From the horse's mouth](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA7.html):

> The specified behavior of aria-labelledby is that the associated label text is announced instead of the link text (not in addition to the link text). When the link text itself should be included in the label text, the ID of the link should be referenced as well in the string of IDs forming the value of the aria-labelledby attribute.

Now to talk about the entire approach. I recommend you do not use `role="menu"` nor `role="menuitem"` here at all. Using them sets the expectation with a screen reader user that the entire menu will behave as the menu bar in his/her OS. I do not know if you have prepared all the necessary keyboard interaction to make that true, but in my experience that rarely happens.

If you do not agree with me, here are some sources to review…

[Using ARIA menus](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_menus):

> Menu widgets must provide keyboard support to navigate all the menu items in the menu. Keyboard support for a menu typically include the cursor keys to navigate between the menu items and open and close popupmenus.

It then goes on to describe all the keyboard interaction you will need to map and provides a block of sample HTML. You may note that it does not use the ARIA attributes you use in the way you use them.

This kind of menu comes up on the [WebAIM mailing list](http://webaim.org/discussion/) regularly. Here is an excerpt from [one of many discussions](http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=5735):

> But to take a step back, it may be first useful to ensure that an ARIA
>   menubar is actually appropriate. This is not typically appropriate for
>   web site navigation - it's intended for a web application's menu bar
>   (think "File...", "Edit...", etc.).

If you take a look at the current state-of-the-art in accessible menus, this one being the [accessible mega-menu from Adobe](https://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/), you will see that Adobe explicitly addresses why it does not use `role="menu"` nor `role="menuitem"`:

> We don't use `role="menu"` for the menu container and `role="menuitem"` for each of the links therein, because if we do, assistive technology will no longer interpret the links as links, but instead, as menu items, and the links in our global navigation will no longer show up when a screen reader user executes a shortcut command to bring up a list of links in the page.

Finally, I encourage you to build a static HTML version of your ideal menu and then test it with a screen reader. You can get a copy of [NVDA for Windows](http://www.nvaccess.org/download/) for free (though [you really should donate](http://www.nvaccess.org/donate/)), and VoiceOver is pre-installed on Macs.

As an aside, [WordPress has a support forum dedicated to accessibility](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/accessibility), so you could also ask there.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this discussion, there are a couple of things you may want to read. First, some history on why the WordPress Accessibility Team cannot enforce accessibility on frontend dropdowns because there are some resources See this discussion: [Make the dropdown navigation menu keyboard accessible](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/make-the-dropdown-navigation-menu-keyboard-accessible) Second, consider studying the code used in one of the default WordPress themes, (2015 or 2016 for example), because those themes are accessibility-ready and include dropdown menus. Third, making your frontend menu accessible is not only dependent on the PHP itself, but also your JavaScript. This is because you will need to make sure your menu is keyboard accessible before Aria even comes into the picture.

Amanda